# Yii: How to remove search from /admin page?

Tags: search, yii

Yii 1.1.13.

On /index.php/employee/admin (autogenerated by Gii and then modified by me) search boxes are shown by zii.widgets.grid.CGridView.

How to remove these search boxes altogether? I want the table without search.

(Note that I don't want search because it misbehaves with my composite models synthesizing data from several tables and transforming it into a different data format for UI than the data format in DB.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the `zii.widgets.grid.CGridView` set the property `filter` to `null`.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array('filter' => null, /* etc */));
```

Comment: When I set filter to null it produces the following error message: http://pastebin.com/SDSRzA9E

Comment: That error message shows you've set the `filter` value to `false`, not to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can remove completely the `'filter'` property.

Answer (score 0):

The error was because of this line:

```
    //'filterModel' => $searchModel,----this is what causes the boxes
```

I have basically commented this line out and the search boxes aren't shown.